# Assign a list of object which has combined keys to the DataSource of a combobox, and set DisplayMember with an expression?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, datasource

I have the following code, The model class `X` will be filled from a database table with a composite key. The service layer method returns a list of `X`.

I want the drop down list shows values of `A + "-" + B + "-" + C`. How to set the `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` of the combo box? Do I need to transform `List<X>` to a list of new class with an added property shows `A + "-" + B + "-" + C`? Can object reference be used as value members?

```
class X // A, B, C are key in the database table
{ 
    string A { get; set; } 
    string B { get; set; } 
    string C { get; set; }
    .... 
}

List<X> GetListOfX() { ..... } // from service layer

var l = GetListOfX();
ComboBox1.DataSource = l; // Or convert it to bindsource?
ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "?"; // How to display A + "-" + B + "-" + C?
ComboBox1.ValueMember = "?"; // Should it not be set so it uses the object reference?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to transform List

*Option 1.* Override `object.ToString` method.

```
class X // A, B, C are key in the database table
{ 
    string A { get; set; } 
    string B { get; set; } 
    string C { get; set; }
    .... 

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", A, B, C);
    }
}

var l = GetListOfX();
ComboBox1.DataSource = l; // that's all, you don't need to set value member or display member
```

*Option 2.* Make a sort of "view model class" (that is, transform `X` instances into another type).

```
class X_ViewModel
{ 
    public X Model { get; private set; }

    public X_ViewModel(X model)
    {
        Model = model;
    }

    string DisplayName 
    {
        get { return string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", A, B, C); }
    }

    .... 

}

var l = GetListOfX().Select(x => new X_ViewModel(x)).ToList();
ComboBox1.DataSource = l;
ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "DisplayName";
ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Model";
```

Personally, I prefer option 2, but it really depends on complexity of `X`, and other use-cases, applicable for `X` instances.